# Explain the output of ICACLS.EXE, line by line, item by item

Tags: windows, icacls

What does this mean:

```
C:\foo\> icacls .
. NT AUTHORITY\IUSR:(M)
  BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS:(M)
  BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS:(OI)(CI)(M)
  NT AUTHORITY\IUSR:(OI)(CI)(M)
  BUILTIN\IIS_IUSRS:(I)(OI)(CI)(RX)
  NT AUTHORITY\IUSR:(I)(OI)(CI)(RX)
  NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
  BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
```

I think the first one means that userid gets Modify permissions on the directory - which means that user can create files, or update files, or delete files. Right?  What is the "NT AUTHORITY\IUSR" user?  Is that really a single user ID?  Is it the default IIS user ID?

ok, the second line I think refers to a group.  It gets the same permissions.

What about all those lines with (I) and (OI) and so on.  Please explain.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From the [Microsoft Article on ICACLS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525%28WS.10%29.aspx)

The entries are users and groups specific to that file (DOMAIN\USER or GROUP), the permissions listed are as follows:

> SIDs may be in either numerical or friendly name form. If you use a numerical form, affix the wildcard character * to the beginning
> of the SID.

> **icacls** preserves the canonical order of ACE (Access Control Entries) entries as:

> - Explicit denials
> - Explicit grants
> - Inherited denials
> - Inherited grants

> *Perm* is a permission mask that can be specified in one of the following forms:

> 1. A sequence of simple rights:
>
> - **F** (full access)
> - **M** (modify access)
> - **RX** (read and execute access)
> - **R** (read-only access)
> - **W** (write-only access)
>
> 2. A comma-separated list in parenthesis of specific rights:
>
> - **D** (delete)
> - **RC** (read control)
> - **WDAC** (write DAC)
> - **WO** (write owner)
> - **S** (synchronize)
> - **AS** (access system security)
> - **MA** (maximum allowed)
> - **GR** (generic read)
> - **GW** (generic write)
> - **GE** (generic execute)
> - **GA** (generic all)
> - **RD** (read data/list directory)
> - **WD** (write data/add file)
> - **AD** (append data/add subdirectory)
> - **REA** (read extended attributes)
> - **WEA** (write extended attributes)
> - **X** (execute/traverse)
> - **DC** (delete child)
> - **RA** (read attributes)
> - **WA** (write attributes)

> Inheritance rights may precede either *Perm* form, and they are applied only to directories:

> - **(OI)**: object inherit
> - **(CI)**: container inherit
> - **(IO)**: inherit only
> - **(NP)**: do not propagate inherit
> - **(I)**: permission inherited from parent container

---

For files, the permission masks are more or less self-explanatory: `R` means you can read the file, `X` allows it to be executed (as a program), and so on.

For other kinds of objects, you will have to browse MSDN:

- [Standard Access Rights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379607%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
- [ACE Inheritance Rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374924%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)
- [Registry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724878%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms685981%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- ...

Inheritance rights in English:

- `(I)` "Inherited": This ACE was inherited from the parent container.
- `(OI)` "Object inherit": This ACE will be inherited by objects placed in this container.
- `(CI)` "Container inherit": This ACE will be inherited by subcontainers placed in this container.
- `(IO)` "Inherit only": This ACE will be inherited (see `OI` and `CI`), but does not apply to this object itself.
- `(NP)` "Do not propagate": This ACE will be inherited by objects and subcontainers *one level deep* – it will not apply to things inside subcontainers.

For the file system, "container" means a folder and "object" means a file, but remember that ACLs can be set on many other kinds of objects, not all of which have a concept of "containers".

Comment: thank you.  I am google-literate and I can read. But I would like an english explanation of just what it means to have (I)RX.  "container inherit" - explain what that means and be specific to the example I provided.

Comment: In that case, you'll need a crash course in NTFS permissions.

Comment: If you are google literate, then you can google "ntfs permissions", "ACL" and "File and registry permission." Frankly, to explain every line in laymans terms is essentially re-writing a whole Technet article for you.

Comment: @Cheeso: [Better now?](http://superuser.com/posts/322431/revisions)

Comment: *One year later...* Yes.  Much better thank you.  As to the others who say: "Go read it", that's what Superuser is for, isn't it?  To answer questions that are not clearly answered elsewhere.

Comment: Strange that `(I)` is not mentioned in the TechNet article. Is there any official (or semi-official) documentation on it?

Comment: I actually found `(I)` mentioned in `icacls /?` on Windows 7.  It also had two separate "Delete" rights - `(D)` was formerly featured in the first list, with `(DE)` instead in the second list.  See https://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html.  It looks like things have changed slightly since then.

Comment: For how the codes relate to what you see in the widows permission boxes eg (OI)(CI) = This folder, subfolders, and files, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27238635/specifying-permisions-with-icacls/27255162#27255162

Comment: Already found all of that. Still wonder what the difference between GR and RD is. How about a link too that _“crash course in NTFS permissions”_ you mentioned? Because, yes, I do indeed need one.

Comment: Google: _“ntfs permissions”_ — No articles to be seen to describe the difference between GR and RD. And same for the other two suggested search terms.