# Deny cut and paste from a folder on file server

Tags: windows-10, permissions, file-permissions, effective-permissions

I have a folder and I need that users can not cut and paste file from this folder (and its subfolders) to other path in their computers.

Is there a solution to implement this?

thanks,

Comment: When you say "users", are you sharing this folder to them via network using the "Share" option in Windows?

Comment: I would try to set an explicit DENY on a test file for a test user account on the DELETE permissions with disabling inheritance too if need. I would get that set on the test file with the test account, sign onto the test account and then try to delete and see if you get access denied. Now try to do a CUT and see if you get access denied. Have to step away so I cannot test at the moment. This post has a section that talks about it some but only deny the DELETE permission as in this example only and test --> https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/prevent-file-deletion-and-file-renaming-in-windows/

Comment: Once you test at the file level, do the same with a test folder and then COPY a file into it. Please ensure once you set deny permissions to a folder for a specific account or group, to only copy files to this area to ensure those copied files get the permissions from the folder. Sometime if you CUT rather than copy, the file permission from where those were CUT are retained rather than the folder permissions they were moved. I always copy to the new folder and then delete the original files if they are not needed for this reason.