# Allow file modification but deny file creation

Tags: file-permissions, windows-server-2019

Is it possible, on Windows Server 2019, to allow users to modify the content of **existing** files in a directory BUT denying them the permission to create new files?

I tried giving them 2 different settings:

- Reading rights on the directory.
- Total control on files and sub-folders

But it seems the former overrides the later; they only have reading access.

In the advanced permissions, file creation and file modification seem to be coupled, so I am wondering if it's even possible to have the setting that I need. Since I want these two attached permissions to be separated...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I believe that Create is Write, and Modify is essentially Delete+Write. I don't think you can have Modify access that doesn't allow Create, as Modify includes Create.

Comment: I just made further tests.

Comment: It seems my double-setting is working with simple text files, but fails with Excel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent users from deleting a folder, while still giving them modify permissions to its contents?](https://superuser.com/questions/720486/how-to-prevent-users-from-deleting-a-folder-while-still-giving-them-modify-perm)

Comment: @harrymc the deletion permissions are separate things and they are rather simple to control. This is a different situation.

Comment: OK, So my double-setting seems to work with Notepad. But it fails with Excel, Word, ... (Microsoft Office 365)

Answer (score 0):

Your solution works with simple text files but not with Excel.

This is because Excel needs to create temporary files while it is executing.
You will have the same problem with other Office products such as Word.

Negative answer: There is no such solution possible with Excel or Word.

Comment: I see. That's rather frustrating.
I'll see if there is a possible way to make these temporary files created localy.

Thank you!

Comment: Office has the bad habit of generating the new document as temporary file, and on save just rename it to the document.