# What kind of Windows privileges would make it so I can delete a file from Linux, but not create one?

Tags: virtual-machine, file-permissions

So I have a folder with some crazy (Windows) ownership privileges.  I have the folder mounted on a Linux guest OS virtual machine shared folder.  I can delete files from the folder using `rm -f`, however I cannot write anything there.

How can that be possible with file permissions in Windows?

BTW:  I can't delete the folder from Windows either -- Go figure...

**Edit:** People want more details about the setup, so here you go:

The host is Windows 8.1 and the guest is Debian 7.  The crazy folder that I am talking about is in the WindowsApps hidden folder under Program Files.  It makes sense that it has crazy privileges... I am just wondering how they are being carried through to Linux like this.

*I am working on getting some privileges data that was requested.*

Comment: Not from a file system. Once the OS (Linux) mounts the FS, it's up to Linux whether to interpret and make any attempt to honor the security restrictions. Even then it has to be able to read and interpret the SAM which I think they do these days, but still... no. It's one reason for encrypting files, whether per-file or whole-disk encryption, because otherwise someone can just boot a live CD or something and read your data.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the version of linux and how you have it mounted (samba? nfs? something else?)?

Comment: Also, permissions readouts from both windows (icacls.exe) and linux (ls -l) and the usernames accessing the files could also be helpful.

Comment: @MaQleod I have not heard of "icacls" before... what is it?

Comment: It lists the ACL for a given file. Windows has some pretty granular perms options. Delete (D) is actually a specific option: http://superuser.com/questions/322423/explain-the-output-of-icacls-exe-line-by-line-item-by-item/322431#322431

Answer (score 1):

In my experience as a sysadmin, I load up windows directories with linux so that I can delete or add files without having to worry about the permissions. That is a security issue.

Comment: What do you mean "load up" -- are you talking about actually booting Linux and mounting Windows?... I know that had better work.

Comment: You are correct in your assumption.

Comment: That's not quite what I was asking... I am pretty much saying "How is this happening???"  I like the thinking though...

Comment: BTW: Welcome to superuser!

Comment: What version of windows are you running and what version of linux... It could be that you are running a version of one that does not understand the other... a version of windows without ext2fs cannot read that or write to it without the update, etc... ext3fs support is not included in many versions of windows as well.

Comment: I added the setup data...

Comment: Debian 7 has ext4 by default right? Windows 8.x does not have full ability to access it. If you installed it with ext2 or ext3 file systems there is more available to you.